# Why are collector resistors grounded in AC small signal analysis of a differential amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, differential, small-signal

[image: Why R_C1 and R_C2 are grounded while doing small signal analysis?]

Why are \$R_{C1}\$ and \$R_{C2}\$ grounded while doing small signal analysis?

Comment: Look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/391776/mosfet-common-source-amplifier-output-impedance-calculation/391785#391785

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the original circuit, but based on the small signal equivalent and the description of it as a "differential amplifier" you are evidently talking about a circuit similar to this differential pair:

[image: differential pair]

<sub>Source: [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Differential_amplifier_long-tailed_pair.svg/800px-Differential_amplifier_long-tailed_pair.svg.png)</sub>

In small signal analysis DC sources are turned off, which means that DC voltage sources are set to 0 V (i.e. a short circuit) and DC current sources are set to 0 A (i.e. an open circuit). In a differential amplifier the collector resistors are connected directly to a DC voltage source (VCC in the above image); that source is turned off for AC small signal analysis (because its AC component is 0) so the collector resistors are grounded (0 V from ground is equivalent to ground).

Comment: Thanks for your answer@Null! Your answer make me to ask another question, what the significance of small signal analysis? or in other words what we try to understand from doing small signal analysis?

Comment: @Learner103 "Small signals" are those that are small enough for the circuit in question that the circuit behaves linearly, which we generally want in an amplifier. Large signals determine the bias parameters of the circuit but have non-linear effects. The idea is to analyze the DC operating point of a circuit to determine its small signal parameters, then analyze its (small signal) linear behavior (e.g. signal gain).

Comment: Got it! So small signal analysis is just a theoretical model or can be done experimentally? If it can be done experimentally, then the circuit I have posted will it work and produce any output voltage as per theory?

Comment: @Learner103 You can verify it experimentally. Build the circuit and bias it with the DC sources you used in your small signal analysis, then apply a small signal to the input and you should see an output signal that matches what the small signal model predicted (assuming the small signal model was correct, and that the signal you applied was small enough for the circuit to behave linearly).

Comment: @Learner103 The small signal goes a bit deeper than this discussion suggests (though it is good.) And it is a purely mathematical concept, not an experimental one. It's not that things behave linearly, by experimental result. It's that in mathematics all continuous portions of curves have a tangent line associated with every point. That tangent line is, by definition, linear. And finally, solving sets of non-linear equations is ***hard***. Solving sets of linear equations is well understood and ***easy***. That's why the concept is used. To simplify analysis. Not to meet experimental result.

Comment: @jonk Sounds like understanding nonlinear curve by Piecewise linear appro. Anyway thanks for your input!!

Comment: @Learner103 If you consider a piecewise approach where the length of each piece diminishes to an infinitesimal, then I suppose you are right. But only then. Otherwise it is not a tangent, but a secant line. Large signal (meaning *not small signal*) analysis is used for finding the DC bias point of a circuit. This gives you the "point" at which, for non-linear device curves, you can find the tangent and use it (for a short range only) as an approximation. But after moving a short distance along that assumed line, you stop, re-evaluate all the DC bias info, and do it again.

Comment: @jonk I get your point! Nice!!

Comment: @Learner103 Spice always (unless you order it otherwise) computes the DC bias point *before* performing a transient analysis (.TRAN card.) This DC bias point step is where it goes through lots and lots of iterations trying to find the DC bias point given gobs of non-linear device models. This is step 0, so to speak. Getting an initial set of values for all the nodes and capacitors and inductors before starting a run. Once it gets there, all it has to do is find a sufficiently short time step and then simply do linear solutions for each time step. Nice approach.

Comment: @Null But in small signal analysis there is no DC bias is it not?

Answer (score 0):

Under the condition of linear circuits, the super position principle/theorem allows you to turn off all voltage and current sources and turn on one voltage/current source at a time and the sum the effects of each individual source.

BJT can be considered linear components whenever the voltage and current sources of the circuit move the bias point by a small amount.

Answer (score 0):

As the controlled current sources in the normal small signal model of all transistors have no parallel impedance, they are perfect current sources and whatever is on the collector side of them have no small signal effect on the emitter and base side of the circuit.

Thus, they are isolated from the rest of the circuit, so they can be left out of the analysis until you need those signals.